# Displaying avatar image in img src Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display logged in user avatar in img `src=""`. I worked in Wordpress and i used this code for display but no results.

```
<img src="<?php global $userdata; get_currentuserinfo(); echo get_avatar( $userdata->ID, 46 ); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation, in combination with the get_avatar method (46 is the size): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

The function assigns a value to $current_user, not $userdata. Here is your updated code

```
<?php
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 46 );
 ?>
```

But I'd like to add that you can also skip this using the method get_current_user_id: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id

```
<?php
    echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 46 );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<figure class="alignnone">
                <?php
                    global $current_user;
                    if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
                    wp_get_current_user();     
                    echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 250 );
                    endif; 
                 ?>
</figure>
```